# Cannot read property 'EVENT' of undefined at Namespace.emit

Tags: node.js, socket.io, socket.io-redis

I'd upgraded my socket.io version from 2 to 3 but the below line:

```
io.sockets.in(room).emit(bag.message.eventType, message)
```

breaks with this error:

```
Cannot read property 'EVENT' of undefined at Namespace.emit (/node_modules/socket.io/dist/namespace.js:170:49)
```

Can someone explain what syntax should go with socket.io@3 for the above code? TIA

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this page https://socket.io/docs/v3/emit-cheatsheet/
you should change your code to this

`io.in(room).emit(bag.message.eventType, message)`

or

`io.sockets.to(room).emit(bag.message.eventType, message)`